# Use fingerprint Scanner in Android phones to read and process data

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I want to read the fingerprint data(multiple fingerprints) using the fingerprint scanner on my phone and store this data uniquely on the cloud. Then using this stored data I want to create a Login Activity type of thing which uses the fingerprint authentication and automatically opens the appropriate activity/webpage for the concerned user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the raw fingerprint data from the mobile's fingerprint reader. It is only to be used for authentication. You should use other methods like integrating external fingerprint readers